# Error using NSass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sass

I've setup NSass from NuGet. It's a managed wrapper around libsass and has a HTTP handler that does on-the-fly compilation of `.scss` files to CSS.

The problem is that the handler throws the following arcane `InvalidOperationException`:

> Found NSass.Wrapper.proxy.dll which cannot exist. Must instead have
>   NSass.Wrapper.x86.dll and NSass.Wrapper.x64.dll. Check your build
>   settings.

I can see that the code and message is copy-pasted from some trickery found here (see bottom):

[Load x64 or a x86 DLL depending upon the platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569257/load-x64-or-a-x86-dll-depending-upon-the-platform)

So my guess was that my web project needed to target x64 specifically, maybe to force a decision on the unmanaged library being used.

That just ends with a `BadImageFormatException` maybe due to IIS Express being 32-bit which I've seen being a PITA with Oracle dependencies - I gave up then, too.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any resolution?

Comment: I have not I'm afraid and I gave up. I have a theory, so I'll post it as an answer and see if it gets shot down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, due to the unmanaged library, `AnyCpu` cannot be used for the project, instead you must pick a target processing platform.

For me that's 64-bit but IIS Express is a 32-bit process. I recall having similar issues with unmanaged references, bitness and IIS Express (32) vs. production (64) with Oracle libraries.

So when IIS Express tries to load the x64-targeted website assembly, it blows up.

I am now looking into a compile time CSS compilation, rather than runtime, using Web Workbench or something.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, and the reason for it was that the NSass.Wrapper.XXX.dll files were not copied into the output directory.

Comment: Have you found a fix for that ? We have the same problem in the unit test sadly.

Comment: Had the same issue and I ended up using https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss instead.

Comment: @JacekGorgoń thanks. Worked out great. The only thing to remember there is to dispose unmanaged resources.